# How to get the time consumption of a linux process from start to finish

Tags: linux

The compile process on my EC2 micro instance is really slow, so I'm gonna leave it running when I go out for a dinner.

Is there anyway to know the time comsumption of the `make` process when I get back from dinner.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `time` ahead of `make`

```
$ time make
```

Comment: thanks, that's so cool. is there a way to fetch the execution time of executed command? like I just finished running make, and use `fetch_running_time`, it give the result